# Magento2 Minicart showing blank count

Tags: mini-cart, magento-2.0.7

When I open the page in Private Browsing / Quote no initialize at that time it show the empty value in minicart count, but it should show **0**.

**If I add product(s) in cart then I can see the number of items in cart**. After that I remove all products from the cart then also I can see the **0** in Cart count.

initial page load I cant see the Item counts in minicart. I have used below code,

```
<span class="counter qty empty" data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got it by using below code,

```
<span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: **cart().summary_count || 0** --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

Comment: you can also use above code, Its also working fine.

Comment: @Nagamani  
file path please?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: **cart().summary_count || 0**

Comment: This fix doesn't work on Magento 2.3.4.

Answer (score 5):

Open your root directory and open `minicar‌​t.phtml`.

The file path is:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/te‌​mplates/cart/minicar‌​t.phtml
```

You have to just replace span with below code,

```
    <span class="counter qty empty"
          data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading">

        <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: cart().summary_count -->
            <span class="counter-number">0</span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <span class="counter-label">
        <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
            <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
```

Run command, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` remove var folder and check again.

Comment: file path please?

Comment: @magentotwo app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, got this error.Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, Also i have one more issue, suppose there are 2 items in cart, on page loading this shows 0 then once page loaded the correct count is showing

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.. don't forget to rebuild static files and clear magento cache after making those above changes.

Comment: I just paste above code to app\design\frontend\zero_theme\mytheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicar‌​t.phtml still the counter not visible if product count "0"

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this issue by removing the following condition:

```
if: cart().summary_count
```

Answer (score 1):

This fix is working on Magento 2.3.4

```
<span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') || 0 --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error, then you should use

```
getCartParam('summary_count')
```

instead

```
cart().summary_count
```

So, in

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/te‌​mplates/cart/minicar‌​t.phtml
```

replace span with below code

```
<span class="counter qty empty"
          data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() }, blockLoader: isLoading">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number">0</span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <span class="counter-label">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
```